# How to draw ellipse equation ax^2+bxy+cy^2+dx+ey+f=0 with parameters a,b,c,d,e,f via openCV ellipse() method?

Tags: opencv, parameters, ellipse, drawellipse

I've struct with Ellipse Equation: Ax^2 + Bxy + Cy^2 + Dx + Ey + F = 0

struct MyEllipse{
  double A, B, C, D, E, F
};

Here is the example of my metadata of detected ellipses
----- METADATA OF DETECTED ELLIPSES -----
Ellipse Equation: Ax^2 + Bxy + Cy^2 + Dx + Ey + F = 0

EllipseID |      A      |      B      |      C      |      D      |      E      |      F      |
       0      6,262e-7      1,371e-9      2,041e-7     -3,583e-4     -8,804e-4      1,000e+0
       1      6,808e-7     -3,807e-9      2,138e-7     -1,293e-4     -9,215e-4      1,000e+0
       2      1,465e-6      7,364e-9      4,929e-7     -3,131e-4     -1,393e-3      1,000e+0

The question is How to draw these ellipses via OpenCV ellipse() method?
I think openCV ellipse() method use these parameters :

img – Image.
center – Center of the ellipse.
axes – Length of the ellipse axes.
angle – Ellipse rotation angle in degrees.
startAngle – Starting angle of the elliptic arc in degrees.
endAngle – Ending angle of the elliptic arc in degrees.
box – Alternative ellipse representation via RotatedRect or CvBox2D. This means that the function draws an ellipse inscribed in the rotated rectangle.
color – Ellipse color.
thickness – Thickness of the ellipse arc outline, if positive. Otherwise, this indicates that a filled ellipse sector is to be drawn.
lineType – Type of the ellipse boundary. See the line() description.
shift – Number of fractional bits in the coordinates of the center and values of axes.

but i don't have these parameters :( I've just you know upper struct Ax^2 + Bxy + Cy^2 + Dx + Ey + F = 0 with struct MyEllipse{
  double A, B, C, D, E, F
};

Please somebody help me?

Comment: Your question is mathematical. You need to find the center(x,y), the size(a,b) and the rotation(r), in order to use cvellipse.

Comment: +1. Here is the [link](http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20070301184409AAXPGhg) for the formulas.